# Ключевое слово super

Tags: javascript

```
  const parent = {
    parentProp: true,
    sayHi: () => console.log('Hello')
  }

  const child = {
    greet: () => super.sayHi()
  }

  Object.setPrototypeOf(child, parent)
  child.greet()
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here

Вопрос:

1. Насколько я понял, интерпретатор ругается на то, что внутри стрелочных функций недопустимо использование `super`, но **почему**?
2. Возможно ли как-нибудь создать пользовательское решение, которое повторяет функциональность `super`? Например, `_super.method()`

Comment: `greet () { super.sayHi()}` -решит проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По первому вопросу.
Стрелочность тут не при чём.
super нельзя использовать в функциях, являющихся свойствами - только в полноценных методах. Это связано с тем, что при обращении через super используется [[HomeObject]] текущего метода, и от него берётся `__proto__`.

Подробнее читайте здесь:
https://learn.javascript.ru/es-object#super

По второму вопросу - не вполне понятно, зачем вам это.
Просто в вашем коде замените стрелочную функцию на

```
greet() {super.sayHi()}
```